# Ruby on Rails views helper link_to is failing with css class attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've used `link_to` helper inside of an `ERB` templates with css class attribute inside of it and it worked.

Now I'm writing same in `helpers\my_helper.rb` and it fails.

Here is my code sample:

```
module PostsHelper
  def post_item(post)
    link_to "#{post.title}", posts_path(post), class: "btn btn-primary btn-block", :role => "button"
  end
end
```

Where could be mistake?

Comment: and what's the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by *it fails*? Is there an error message? What does it say?

Comment: There's a SyntaxError exception being thrown when I try to call `post_item(post)` in my view template.

Comment: So, basically I couldn't figure out from `link_to` api docs where is mistake, because I'm doing the same as docs says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a syntax error because you mix the old and the new hash syntax. Just use

```
link_to post.title, posts_path(post), 
        :class => "btn btn-primary btn-block", :role => "button"
```

or

```
link_to post.title, posts_path(post), 
        class: "btn btn-primary btn-block", role: "button"
```